# Strava, how does segment get created?

Tags: strava

I've just been introduced to Strava app.

I heard Strava has a concept of `segment` where individual's performance is recorded and compared.

Just out of curiosity, how would `segment` get created?

I don't think Strava employees would create them manually..
What would be their algorithm to add / modify / remove `segment`?

Comment: The site provides for excellent explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article explains most of the issues

https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216918227

For example 'Box Hill' is the most popular Strava climb in the world. There are many segments:

https://www.strava.com/segments/3623111 - this one is not necessarily ideal because it has a right turn at the start across a road open to traffic , and while this accounts for 13m of the climb and it's not a very busy road, it's still less than ideal and riders who ride this route (100,000+ people https://www.cyclist.co.uk/news/6788/box-hill-crowned-stravas-most-popular-hill-climb-segment) might favourite a different segment. However it is very well named - 'Box Hill Roundabout to Summit (post box)' makes it clear to a rider what segment they are targeting

This segment is poor quality:

https://www.strava.com/segments/1234330

in that the trace does not match the road, and it claims to be 'full climb', yet the elevation is below the previous one

This one has been created by someone selling a book of cycling climbs I believe:

https://www.strava.com/segments/6695759

and calls it self 'Official 100Climbs' . It is a bad segment because it is not properly described.

This similar segment makes it clearer

https://www.strava.com/segments/1450512

'Boxhill Roundabout to Cafe' - its end point is a cafe, and not the actual summit. While this is fine, and for such an overwhelmingly popular segment it makes sense to perhaps have different segments, as there wouldn't necessarily be any consensus about the end of the climb - some people might target the cafe & car park and stop there, while others would prefer the true summit, so the segment should at a minimum make it clear what it is, because if you are targeting a very popular segment you don't want to slow down short of your goal or something.

If you are riding in, say, remote rural Asia, then there often won't be any segments, so you can create them after riding yourself (you can't create the segment without riding it, but you will be KoM/QoM after creating a new segment if you are the only one to have ridden it). In a developed country in a populated area, probably most segments will exist already, but if you feel that an existing segment is not very good, then you simply create a better one (e.g., you might feel that starting before a traffic light is a bad idea, and create a new segment after a traffic light). Over time your segment might be favourited by other users, and will show up in their Stravas. Poor quality segments will be hidden - e.g., you might be shown 40 out of 200 segments on a particular trip, where better quality segments tend to get viewed and favourited more

Some segments are anti-social, e.g., there are people setting 30mph speeds on shared paths, and you can report such segments as hazardous, which won't delete them, but it will hide them from leaderboards. However this is not particularly well-policed by Strava in my experience. https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216918217-Updated-Flagging-a-Segment-as-Hazardous

Comment: " In a developed country in a populated area, probably most segments will exist already" I cannot really agree with that. I have already created about a hundred segments in the Czech Republic and cycling is reasonably popular here. Yes, in the UK, there numerous nonsense segments, but here it is quite different. Sometimes one just creates a segment where another already is but is illogical, but mostly one creates completely new ones. I never get to be shown 200 segments around on a trip around here and the hidden ones are usually just  a few.

Comment: Of course parts of the world famous for grand tours or spring classics or other races and famous holiday areas like Mallorca will also be already overfilled with segments, but that is not where most people live.

Comment: Ok yeah I probably was in one of the most popular MAMIL areas in England, even.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can create segments, ordinary users make them, there are too many of them to be created by the company. Go to your activity, choose More and Create Segment. Then just follow the comments. See https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216918157-Create-a-Segment

Some old segments may be automatically created. They are typically named by some close address followed by "climb" even in non-English speaking areas. They are the minority. I do not know what the process to create them was but someone likely had to ride there first but I do not know how many people. Some of these have very few attempts, though.

Only people who created the segment can Edit and Remove them. Go to "My Segments", choose your segment and do what you wish. You can only report other people's segments as dangerous, but you cannot do anything to them yourself.